# WCF Service Send Email On Outlook | Exception from HRESULT

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, outlook, windows-server-2012-r2

I have created a WCF Project  in .NET 4.5  to send emails from Outlook 2013 Or 2016  and host it on windows server 2012 and iis 8.

When run Service from Visual studio 2019 in **windows 10** everything **works** as expected but when deployed to:

- IIS 8 in windows server 2012

...the following error happens:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory
>   for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).    at
>   Service.Method

I also did DCOM Config that I found solution from other posts but still I have same problem.

i want attach meeting and reminder in email , for this i used outlook .(outlook connected to Exchange)
. if there is other way please say it.

Comment: _["Current **licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server** to service client requests, unless those **clients** themselves have **licensed copies of Office**. Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA)"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)_

Comment: Also, DCOM Config would _not_ be useful if both IIS and Office are on the same machine

Answer (score 1):

No Office app, Outlook included, can be used from a Windows service. Extended MAPI (C++ or Outlook) can be, but that means a profile would either need to be manually configured first,  or you would need to programmatically build it first. In case of C#, you can use the [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - it wraps the Extended MAPI system).

If you are only sending messages, why not use straight SMTP? If you are sending through an Exchange Server, why not use [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange) (whcih has a [.Net wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633710(v%3Dexchg.80)))

Comment: thanks for your feedback.
i want send reminder and meeting time in email , SMTP does not support meeting time.
can i send meeting time or reminder with EWS ?

Comment: Of course SMTP does - Outlook can send appointment invitations through SMTP just fine. You need to create a suitably formatted text/calendar MIME message.